# How to destroy a logging handler? (and should I do that?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

My current program consist of a never ending loop of a set of events, logging in each of the iterations has a unique id attached.

```
class Logging:

    # a unique identifier for each logging handler, updated below
    log_id = None

    # logger handler
    log = None

    @staticmethod
    def reset_logger_with_new_id():
        log = logging.getLogger(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(message)s')
        handler_console = logging.StreamHandler()
        level = logging.DEBUG if 'DEV' in os.environ else logging.INFO
        handler_console.setLevel(level)
        handler_console.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(handler_console)
        # set the class logging handler
        Logging.log = log

if __name__ == "__main__":
     # initialization
     Logging.reset_logger_with_new_id()
     Logging.log.info("initialization things happening")
     # things happening
     while True:
         Logging.reset_logger_with_new_id()
         # the actions loop
         Logging.log.info("something in the action loop")
         something()
         Logging.log.info("something else in the action loop")
         something_else()
```

The output is

```
2019-11-09 22:03:28,998 [07a48712-cf6f-49ca-ba87-c47ec9703d0c] initialization things happening
2019-11-09 22:04:29,615 [2e5f53cf-df08-4b4e-bdf9-2820a0e80a43] something in the action loop
2019-11-09 22:04:38,704 [2e5f53cf-df08-4b4e-bdf9-2820a0e80a43] something else in the action loop
2019-11-09 22:05:38,765 [21a41a51-338b-4a9f-8ed5-cd0ac40b3c20] something in the action loop
2019-11-09 22:05:47,834 [21a41a51-338b-4a9f-8ed5-cd0ac40b3c20] something else in the action loop
(...)
```

Since a new logger is created in each iteration:

- should I care about something growing and ultimately overflowing?
- if so - how to destroy an existing logger? (the previous one, which I would destroy at the beginning of `reset_logger_with_new_id()`)

**The documentation mentions [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.close) but it is not clear to me whether this is what I should call to avoid the problem above.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will keep eating memory as new logger instances are created. There is multiple ways to deal with this. If you really need new loggers you can destroy the previous logger with `del logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict[name]`. I would however recommend instead either use a formatter to just print the logs with a unique id per iteration, or rename the logger. The code below does the latter:

```
import logging
import uuid
import os
from time import sleep

class Logging:
    # logger handler
    log = None

    @staticmethod
    def initialize_logging():
        log = logging.getLogger(str(uuid.uuid4()))
        log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(message)s')
        handler_console = logging.StreamHandler()
        level = logging.DEBUG if 'DEV' in os.environ else logging.INFO
        handler_console.setLevel(level)
        handler_console.setFormatter(formatter)
        log.addHandler(handler_console)
        # set the class logging handler
        Logging.log = log

    @staticmethod
    def reset_logger_with_new_id():
        name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        Logging.log.name = name
        logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict[name] = Logging.log # this is required so it can still be found by logging.getLogger(name)
        return

def something():
    pass
something_else = something

if __name__ == "__main__":
     # initialization
     Logging.initialize_logging()
     Logging.log.info("initialization things happening")
     # things happening
     while True:
         Logging.reset_logger_with_new_id()
         # the actions loop
         Logging.log.info("something in the action loop")
         something()
         Logging.log.info("something else in the action loop")
         something_else()
         sleep(1)
```